# Is there a better way to generate HTML from an XPATH string?

Tags: html, xpath

We want to write JUnit tests for complex java code that uses Selenium webDriver on very complex web pages.

We found that saving the web pages always alters the xpaths, so that's out. Mocking the WebDriver, WebElements etc. was difficult and messy.

In the end, we've chosen to generate the HTML files for the XPATHS used by the logic, then have the webDriver simply load the test HTML pages.

We wrote the code below and it works *most* of the time.  But before we develop it further, we're asking if there's a simpler/better way or a library or utility for this purpose.

```java
   public void generateHtml(String xPath) {

        ArrayList<String> htmlDoc = new ArrayList<>();
        htmlDoc.add("<!DOCTYPE html>");

        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)]");
        Matcher matcher;

        String[] tokens = xPath.substring(1).split("/");
        ArrayList<String> closeTags = new ArrayList<>();

        for (final String token : tokens) {
            final String tag = token.split("\\[")[0];

            // collect closing tags
            closeTags.add(mkCloseTag(tag));

            // get the index if present
            matcher = patt.matcher(token);
            int idx = 0;
            if (matcher.find()) {
                idx = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
            }

            // if indexed, create enough empty tag pairs up to the indexed one
            if (idx > 0) {
                for (int i = 1; i < idx; ++i) {
                    htmlDoc.add(mkTag(tag) + idx);
                    htmlDoc.add(mkCloseTag(tag));
                }
            }

            // append an extra tag pair if idx is 1
            if (idx == 1) {
                closeTags.add(mkTag(tag) + idx);
                closeTags.add(mkCloseTag(tag));
            }

            htmlDoc.add(mkTag(tag));
        }

        // append all the close-tags
        Collections.reverse(closeTags);
        htmlDoc.addAll(closeTags);

        for(String t : htmlDoc) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
```

Example of an xpath we're dealing with:

```
/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/input
```

Comment: I really don't understand your intentions because if you build an XML tree for wich some XPath expression would result in a not empty selection...Are you really testing your XPath expression or your fixture for the test?

Comment: We're testing ONLY the logic that uses the data extracted from web pages.  As a proper unit test, we want to controllthe "test" data (web pages).  When we save a sample web page, the xpaths change among other problems - otherwise that would be the solution.

Comment: If you are testing only the logic that uses the data, why bother about how is it get? Just store the "test" data in a format that suit you and change/extend the method/object that provide them.

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what we want to do - store the test data in a convenient format.  However, the Selenium webdriver IS THE OBJECT that retrieves the data.  We can't modify it, nor do we want to wrap it in another object.  Our current method of generating HTML works for most of our web pages - it fails on the larger, more complex ones.  This is why we were hoping there's a better way.  We'll just proceed to develop our xpath->html utility unless we find a better way.